# Can php ignore the suggested ip for the ftp data channel and go direct to server?

Tags: php, ftp

I've been downloading a remote file from a client successfully for a while now and for some reason their server is now returning a private ip. FileZilla is smart enough to use the server address.

```
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
```

I don't see a way to do this using php's built in ftp code.

```
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

    ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $downloaded_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {

        printf("Successfully downloaded %s\n", $downloaded_file);

    } else {
        printf("There was a problem downloading %s\n %s\n", 
              $server_file, 
              print_r(error_get_last(), TRUE)
        );
        exit(1);
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

**Is there a way to have php ignore the suggested ip for the data channel and use the server's ip?**

Comment: [Nope](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55651). Anyway if you call `ftp_pasv(..., FALSE)`, shouldn't your connection use an active connection instead (with `PORT` commands instead of `PASV`)?

Comment: If you are behind a gateway, should't you use passive mode?  `ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);`

Comment: I was using passive. That was an artifact from testing, forgot to revert it.

Comment: @CodeCaster you're 100% correct. read the patch and article here http://www.elitehosts.com/blog/php-ftp-passive-ftp-server-behind-nat-nightmare/ which explains exactly what I'm going through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible as of 5.6.18 / 7.0.2 using the following option:

```
ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

[Relevant commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/90a26a4844d1acfecb3bd0842da333f8bddd45c6)

Comment: Was looking for something like for a long time. Thanks!